# Compare Software Version Across a dynamic set of server names using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

i wanted to compare the version of a software installed on multiple servers, the list of servers are part of a DAG cluster and as you can see below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32\drivers> Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup | select -ExpandProperty servers | select name

Name
----
VMAPPSNODE3
VMAPPSNODE2
VMAPPSNODE1
```

Now the number of servers which are a part of DAG can be between 1--16, i wanted a way to compare the software version of a particular software in thsi servers.

I could do some thing like below but as you can see the No of DAG servers is not fixed and its a dynamic variable,

```
$VMAPPSNODE3 = get-wmiobject Win32_product |?{.....
$VMAPPSNODE2 = get-wmiobject Win32_product |?{.....
.
.
.
.
.
```

i tried compare-object but it only supports comparison of two objects, how could i attain comparison of the same software version of a product across multiple servers and let me know a "True" or "False" statement indicating if the software version is same across all servers or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a foreach-loop. Try this:

```
Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup | % {
    $name = $_.Name
    Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter "name like 'Powershell%'" -ComputerName $name | % { 
        New-Object psobject -Property {
            ComputerName = $name
            Version = $_.Version
        }
    }
}
```

Sample-output:

```
ComputerName                                      Version
------------                                      -------
VMAPPSNODE3                                       3.0.4.0 
VMAPPSNODE2                                       3.0.4.0
....
```

I've used and recommend `-Filter` in `Get-WmiObject` instead of `where-object (?)`. `Where-Object` queries all products and then filter using `where`, while the `-Filter` parameter does it during the search, which is alot faster. Both ways work, it's just a timesaver (but requires a slightly different filter-style then `where-object`)

You can expand this however you like, ex. True/false: There's only one version in the DAG

```
@(Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup | % {
    $name = $_.Name
    Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter "name like 'Powershell%'" -ComputerName $name | % { 
        New-Object psobject -Property {
            ComputerName = $name
            Version = $_.Version
        }
    }
} | Select-Object Version -Unique).Count -eq 1

True
```